# How to acquire lock on a file located at a NAS mount path across multiple JVMs running on different servers in Java/ Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file, file-locking

How to acquire lock on a file located at a NAS mount path across multiple JVMs running on different servers in Java/ Spring Boot.

Tried FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter. It picked up the file. However other file in same directory was not picked up by other jvm

Comment: I would try to rename the file (using UUID.randomUUID() in new target filename as „Lock Token“).

Comment: @ChristophDahlen Thanks for your reply. I did think of this approach but in case of app shutdown or during deployments if app is brought down, file will stay renamed and won't be picked up by the poller. It will require manual intervention to rename the file back to original.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ChristophDahlen was able to resolve it using nio-locker in spring integration